# cifar100, load only 100 images

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to load only 10 images of CIFAR100 using keras, I tried this:

```
_,cifar100_test = tf.keras.datasets.cifar100.load_data().take(10)
```

It seems that the previous line is loading the whole images, then take 100 because my raspberry pi is showing 'memory error' while loading the dataset!

Any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

There's no enough ram memory for loading the data use this `free -mh` to check the empty memory.